# Understanding how a method is used after using new keyword

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, javascript-objects

Im familiar with creating new instances of objects using classes like so:

```
    class Person {
     constructor(name, age) {
     this.name = name;
     this.age = age;
    }
    call() {
    console.log(this.name)
    }
}

const john = new Person('john', 23);
john.call();
```

But i've been seeing code that looks like this

```
const deliveryClient = new Kk.DeliveryClient({
projectId: 'xxx',
});
```

The part that is confusing to me is what does this Kk class look like behind the scenes?

Comment: It's just a class declared inside an object. Otherwise no different.

Comment: It's most likely part of an object that was imported from another file.

Comment: For the record, it's not a `Kk` class object, it's a `DeliveryClient` object. The `DeliveryClient` property of `Kk` is a function that can be used as a constructor.